# How do I rename a movie clip in Flash CS4?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I renamed a movie clip in Flash CS4. After renaming and updating any references I had to it, the swf would still play fine. However, I could no longer get to any of the actionscript I had in the movie clip. It would still execute, but I couldn't get to the script anywhere in the Flash CS4 UI. Any ideas? The only way I was able was to get the code back was to roll back my changes and not rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem was like this:

Your original movieclip: 'originalMC'
The call upon actionscript in the movieclip: 'originalMC.someRandomFunction()'

If you rename your movieclip in the Flash IDE the call wont work.

Otherwise I have to say that your statement is very vague. If you maybe could show an example of your code. I don't understand "but I couldn't get to the script anywhere in the Flash CS4 UI".

OH ... I think I do understand now. If you have actionscript inside of a movieclip, as it is common in as1 & as2, that code can easily vanish if you change type of the movieclip or even if you rename it.

What the hell am I talking ...

Comment: na i renamed the movieclip in my library, then opened the movie clip on the stage, and the frame with the actionscript was gone. but it still executed when i ran it.

Comment: That is a very weird behavior.

Comment: i know people probably think im insane or doing something wrong. im tempted to make a video of it... anyway i gave up and rewrote it in as3 (designer who gave me the project had started it in as2)

Comment: I don't think that you are insane :) Software happens ... But I think you decided good with porting to as3.